# Save active in coockies on dark mode

Tags: java, cookies

I have a code with checkbox

```
NioApp.ModeSwitch = function () {
    var toggle = $('.dark-switch');

    if ($body.hasClass('dark-mode')) {
      toggle.addClass('active');

    } else {
      toggle.removeClass('active');

    }

    toggle.on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $body.toggleClass('dark-mode');

    });
  };
```

How to save a coockies when class dark-mode is active on all pages.

Comment: This doesn't look like java.

Answer (score -1):

Here functions of save and get cookie for you;

```
    function createCookie(name) {
  
    document.cookie = name
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

For example;

```
if ($body.hasClass('dark-mode')) {
  toggle.addClass('active');

} else {
  toggle.removeClass('active');

}

toggle.on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $body.toggleClass('dark-mode');
  createCookie("dark-mode=on");

});
```

Comment: This doesn't look like java.

Comment: The question is tagged java, not javascript. Not sure why, through.